# History of simplicial complex

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, ho.history-overview, simplicial-stuff

It is easy to find the definition of a simplicial complex:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex

I am interested in the history and first occurrences of the concept.
When did people start studying those objects?

Comment: Probably it goes back to the origins of algebraic topology around the turn of the (20th) century, which at that time went by the name of "combinatorial topology," and people mostly worked with simplicial homology and triangulations of manifolds.

Comment: Note that you can ask "history" questions at [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There is a long historical development here.  I recommend reading the first few chapters of Dieudonne's "A history of algebraic and differential topology, 1900-1960" for an account of a good chunk of it.

Comment: The Google Books Ngram Viewer gives the first occurrence of the term "simplicial complex" in 1881, but Google Books does not give any sources. Of course the term could have appeared earlier under different names and in different languages.